# Proper way in Rust to store a reference in a struct

Tags: rust, immutability

What is the proper way to store a reference in a struct and operate on it given this example:

```
// Trait that cannot be changed
pub trait FooTrait {
    pub fn open(&self, client: &SomeType);
    pub fn close(&self);
}

pub struct Foo {
    // HOW TO STORE IT HERE???
    // client: &SomeType,
}

impl FooTrait for Foo {
    pub fn open(&self, client: &SomeType) {
        // HOW TO SAVE IT HERE?
        // NOTE that &self cannot be changed into &mut self because the trait cannot be modified
        // smth like self.client = client;
    }

    pub fn close(&self) {
        // HOW TO DELETE IT HERE?
        // NOTE that &self cannot be changed into &mut self because the trait cannot be modified
    }
}
```

Is there a design pattern that could fit to my snippet?

Answer (score 2):

This is horribly complicated on its surface because of lifetime issues. Rust is designed to guarantee memory safety, but this pattern creates an untenable situation where the caller of `FooTrait::open()` needs some way to tell Rust that the `client` borrow will outlive `*self`.  If it can't do that, Rust will disallow the method call.  Actually making this work with references is probably not feasible, as `Foo` needs a lifetime parameter, but the code that creates the `Foo` may not know the appropriate lifetime parameter.

You *can* make this pattern work by combining a few things, but *only* if you can modify the trait.  If you can't change the definition of the trait, then what you are asking is impossible.

- You need an `Option` so that `close` can clear the value.
- You need interior mutability (a `Cell`) to allow mutating `self.client` even if `self` is a shared reference.
- You need something other than a bare reference.  An owned value or a shared ownership type like `Rc` or `Arc`, for example.  These types sidestep the lifetime issue entirely.  You can make the code generic over [`Borrow<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) to support them all at once.

```
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

pub trait FooTrait {
    fn open(&self, client: impl Borrow<SomeType> + 'static);
    fn close(&self);
}

pub struct SomeType;

pub struct Foo {
    client: Cell<Option<Box<dyn Borrow<SomeType>>>>,
}

impl FooTrait for Foo {
    fn open(&self, client: impl Borrow<SomeType> + 'static) {
        self.client.set(Some(Box::new(client)));
    }

    fn close(&self) {
        self.client.set(None);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, very good explanation, unfortunately I can't change the trait as it comes from some Android generated code

Comment: @Mihai I don't think you can do what you're asking then, without the use of `unsafe` code that has high probability of introducing undefined behavior.

Comment: As a last resort I'm ok with `unsafe` as well because `open` will be called from only one thread

Comment: @Mihai Threads aren't relevant. The problem is that the `SomeType` value could be dropped before the `Foo` value, which creates a use-after-free bug, and therefore UB. If this is generated code you may wish to file a bug report against the project responsible for the code generator.

Comment: It seems the API designer does not want a trait implementation to cache the client. Either it is intended as a use-and-forget scenario, or the trait implementation would clone the client, or save some info extracted from the client.